# regex only spaces - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I need to filter a field composed of only spaces; something like:

```
if (word == /((\s)+)/ ) return 'no name'
```

but it doesn't work ... any other ideas?
thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 14):

You should use `if(/^\s+$/.test(word))`. (Notice the `^` and `$`, without them the regex will hold for any string that has at least a space-like character)

Comment: Thanks Gabi, this is the right way. But so I test all words with al most one space, and I wanted to filter the strings with only spaces

Comment: rob, you were too quick and I didn't see you comment. Your suggestion is the right for me - it works fine. Thank you all, guys!

Comment: you people are too fast. i never get to answer a question I actually know :P

Comment: **NOTE:** This does not account for multiline strings

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `space` character instead of the `\s`.

```js
'   '.match(/ +/)
''.match(/ +/)
```

Output

```json
["   ", index: 0, input: "   ", groups: undefined]'
null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this same check with `!word.trim()` as well, and ignore regex completely.

Answer (score -2):

How about **NOT** checking "word" by RegExp but using RegExp to replace all whitespaces and look what's left. If it's empty "word" is only composed by whitespaces:

```
   if (word.replace(/\s+/, "") === "") {
      console && console.log("empty string found!");
      return 'no name';
   }
```

Comment: That code is subtly different from OP's: Yours allows the empty string; OP's and the other answer don't. Also, `console & ...` makes no sense and the parens around `word` are redundant.

Comment: I don't think so, he want's to find fields composed of only spaces, so I wrote a check to find it. 

What you do with the result inside the statement or if you want to switch the statement to !==, and if you write it to console even only for testing or development - does this really matter?

And sure, the parens are redundant, but also this doesn't harm the solution itself in any way, isn't it?

Comment: But, you are using regex!

Comment: OK, that's right, the text is wrong, I will change that, THX!